# Python - defining multiple versions of a class

Tags: python, django

I want to define two different versions of a same class:

```
mail.prod.py
mail.devel.py
```

only one should be used/imported based on environment type (prod/devel). Can I provide some sort of abstraction that frees the other classes from knowing whether to import prod or devel?

Comment: You could make a `mail` module where `mail/__init__.py` imports from `mail.production` or `mail.development` depending on an environment variable. Why can't you merge them into one class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using environment variables. You can do this in Windows via this [link](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm) and Linux via a command similar to

```
EXPORT app_env="PROD"
```

Now, assuming you've set a variable named `app_env` in your environment, you can do this in your mail module's `__init__.py`:

```
import os
if "app_env" in os.environ and os.environ['app_env'] == "PROD":
    import prod as mailcfg
else:
    import devel as mailcfg
```

At this point, your module should be imported and accessible using `mailcfg.variable` or `mailcfg.DoSomething()`

Your mail module needs three files in it:

```
mail/
    __init__.py
    prod.py
    devel.py
```